# Apache not catching relative paths in .htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apache doesn't catch the below .htaccess rule if requests are made by relative paths.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
```

E.g. if the HTML sent to the client includes:

```
<link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Apache will skip the rule. If however the HTML includes:

```
<link href="http://host.com/CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it works just fine.

The same goes for relative paths inside e.g. CSS files, like:

```
background-image:url(../images/image.png);
```

that is, if the requested CSS has first been requested with the full path name.

How is this possible?

Comment: What's the idea with the rules? I don't see they are doing anything, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second RewriteRule will only rewrite the search path internally, on the server that is. So, when a relative search path is sent to the client, say:

```
<link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

whatever is referred to as `$1` in the second RewriteRule will be included in the search path.

So, if e.g. www.example.com/en/ is requested by the client and a HTML document including the relative path `href="CSS/main.css"` is sent back, the client will expect the css file to be located in `www.example.com/en/CSS`, not `www.example.com/CSS/`. Naturally then if the css document in the example is referred to with a direct path like: `href="http://example.com/CSS/main.css"` the document will be correctly retrieved.